# invalid or unknown type App.ImageFile.Type for field :filename Phoneix App

Tags: google-cloud-storage, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm attempting to use Arc to allow for uploading images to Google Cloud Storage, (following this - https://maartenvanvliet.nl/2017/08/05/arc_uploads_to_google_cloud_storage/) however, I'm getting a compile error when running `mix ecto.migrate`:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/codsonline/assets/image.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) invalid or unknown type App.ImageFile.Type for field :filename
    lib/ecto/schema.ex:1886: Ecto.Schema.check_type!/3
    lib/ecto/schema.ex:1507: Ecto.Schema.__field__/4
    lib/codsonline/assets/image.ex:8: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in 
Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

I've changed my schema from:

```
  schema "images" do
    field :filename, :string
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end
```

to:

```
  schema "images" do
    field :filename, App.ImageFile.Type
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end
```

My uploaders/image_file.ex:

```
defmodule Codsonline.ImageFile do
  use Arc.Definition

  # Include ecto support (requires package arc_ecto installed):
  use Arc.Ecto.Definition

  @versions [:original]

  def __storage, do: Arc.Storage.GCS

  def gcs_object_headers(:original, {file, _scope}) do
    [content_type: MIME.from_path(file.file_name)]
  end

end
```

Have I got the syntax wrong somewhere?

**Update**

@dogbert pointed out I wasn't Using Codsonline instead of App, the below now works:

```
  schema "images" do
    field :filename, Codsonline.ImageFile.Type
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end
```

Comment: Have you defined an `App.ImageFile` module like in that post?

Comment: Just added to post @Dogbert

Comment: So are you using `App.` in the schema or `Codsonline.`?

Comment: Yep hadn't changed it from App to Codsline.